# Incomplete Object error when updating site (after Drupal timeout)

Tags: 7

I (foolishly) tried to enable an installed module whilst on my shared hosting. The site times out, which isn't all together unsurprising. However now I get this error message whenever I try and make any updates to the site (enable any modules, clear cache, run cron etc.)

Any thoughts as to the cause. Here is the error in full.

> Fatal error: views_plugin_display::destroy(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "metatag_views_plugin_display_extender_metatags" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/xxxxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_display.inc on line 272

If it makes any difference it was the Metatag module I was trying to enable.

Comment: I would try enabling Devel, then from the admin menu go to Flush all caches -> Class registry

Comment: The flaw in that plan is that enabling the Devel module creates the error.

Comment: good catch :) You could try disabling and re-enabling metatag

Comment: I downloaded the database from phpmyadmin and uploaded it to a backup of the files I had from half a week a go. For some reason this seems to be working fine, because you know... Drupal doesn't have to make sense. I'll see if I get any problems when I reupload to live server.

Comment: But basically whilst this isn't a 'fix' to the problem it does seem to be a 'solution' (touch wood).

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when running update after disabling Metatag and Metatag: Views. It went away when I re-enabled those two modules.

That also seems to have fixed some other issues I was having with the modules form; it would white screen on me after disabling (certain?) modules, although I could return to the Admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when disabling Metatag: Views and everything get back to work smoothly enabling again. The problems seems to be related to this issue:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1278534